# Android: How to transform one LiveData object into a List of LiveData objects?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack

This is kind of a piggy back question from my last [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107265/android-livedata-how-to-do-an-arraylistlivedataretrofitobject) but how would I be able to transform a `LiveData<object>` into a `LiveData<ArrayList<object>>` so I can put it in my RecyclerView?

I have tried using Transforms.map and switchmap but I haven't been successful.

Comment: you only have this problem because you have a `List<LiveData<retrofitObject>>`  instead of a `LiveData<Map<String, RetrofitObject>>`, and that's entirely a limitation of your own code.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how would that work with Room?

Comment: Most likely MediatorLiveData.